# Entity Framework Core: how to map different object instances to the same entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How could I map different object instances of an entity to the same row into a datatable using Entity Framework Core?

In another word, how does Entity Framework Core compare entities which are not yet inserted into a database (otherwise I guess it only has to compare the primary key) and figures out that two objects should be mapped to a single entity? Does it compare instance references? Or call the default Equality operator?

Summarizing my problem, let's imagine I have a school containing students and teacher, and that I want one data row to be created for each teacher name but I cannot reuse the same teacher instance, how could I tell EF to do that?

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class SchoolGenerator
{
    public static void CreateASchool(SchoolContext context)
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student(){Name = "Student 1", Teacher = new Teacher(){Name = "Teacher 1"}},
            new Student(){Name = "Student 2", Teacher = new Teacher(){Name = "Teacher 1"}}, // I cannot re-use the previous instance of Teacher 1 for this student
            new Student(){Name = "Student 3", Teacher = new Teacher(){Name = "Teacher 2"}},
            new Student(){Name = "Student 4", Teacher = new Teacher(){Name = "Teacher 2"}},
        };

        context.Students.AddRange(students);
        context.SaveChanges(); // I want to create only TWO teacher rows, one by name, and FOUR student rows
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
var teacher1 = ...;
var teacher2 = ...;

List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student(){Name = "Student 1", Teacher = teacher1 },
        new Student(){Name = "Student 2", Teacher = teacher1 },
        new Student(){Name = "Student 3", Teacher = teacher2 },
        new Student(){Name = "Student 4", Teacher = teacher2 },
    };

context.Students.AddRange(teacher1, teacher2);
context.Students.AddRange(students);

context.SaveChanges();
```

This assumes that the teachers are created elsewhere and saved in the same unit of work as the students.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo, thanks but this would be too simple, in my case, instances are coming from elsewhere and every student has a different instance of teacher attached.

Comment: You can just attach the teachers to the students and mark them as not modified. Updated the code.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it. "This, of course, assumes they have their primary key property set." How could they have a PK set if they are not yet inserted?

Comment: The initial answer was right. I re-updated the code. You get the teacher instances from somewhere else, you assign them to the students and then you save them all in the same unit of work.

Comment: ok thanks. But this is not my question, I would like to map different instances to the same entity, the example I gave is simplified but just imagine I cannot change the teacher instance associated to each student.

Comment: You keep talking about some requirement outside what you have told us that is limiting what you can do. Update the question with more context and then we'll help you solve your actual issue.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Class instances are deserialized from an external file and populated in a readonly property that I cannot access. As a result, same "teachers" are deserialized as different instances, and there is nothing I could do against it.

Comment: So `Student.Teacher` is readonly? Well, you're going to have to create new student objects that point to distinct `Teacher` objects. Or push back and ask that `Student.Teacher` becomes a writable property. Treat this as a view model, and copy the details to your data model.

Answer (score -2):

Why did you code DbContext manually? Use Scaffold-DbContext instead.

1) Re-design your Student table by adding new "TeacherID" column in SQL Server

2) Create relationship between Student and Teacher tables in SQL Server

3) Run Scaffold-DbContext to update DbContext and entities

4) Use code below

```
var teacher1 = new Teacher(){ Name = "Teacher 1" };
var teacher2 = new Teacher(){ Name = "Teacher 2" };

context.Teachers.AddRange(teacher1, teacher2);

List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student(){Name = "Student 1", TeacherID = teacher1.ID },
        new Student(){Name = "Student 2", TeacherID = teacher1.ID },
        new Student(){Name = "Student 3", TeacherID = teacher2.ID },
        new Student(){Name = "Student 4", TeacherID = teacher2.ID }
    };

context.Students.AddRange(students);
context.SaveChanges();
```

[image]

Comment: DbContext has been scaffolded, it is just an explanation. And this is not what I asked, if I could change the instance o f teacher attached to every student, there will be no question asked.